# How to handle IntutTypeMismatchException to get correct input from user again without rerunning the program?

Tags: java, input, exception, java.util.scanner

I have this program code. If user enter input in string format such as "Three",i want that program show error message and prompt the user again to enter proper input without rerunning the program. But the program doesn't take input again.

```
//Program to get radius form user & calculate area of circle.
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaOfCircle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final float PI=3.14f;
    double rad=0.0;
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter radius of circle: ");
            rad = input.nextDouble();
            break;
            } 
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter radius in proper  format");
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Area of circle is: "+(PI*rad*rad));
}

}
```

The output is like this.

```
Enter radius of circle: 
Three
Please enter radius in proper  format
Enter radius of circle: 
Please enter radius in proper  format
Enter radius of circle: 
Please enter radius in proper  format
Enter radius of circle: 
Please enter radius in proper  format
(infitely...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrong input is still in the scanner. Try to do a `input.nextLine()` in your catch clause.